# Mongoose's Date is not functioning as intended

Tags: javascript, date, mongoose, discord.js

As the title says, I have been working on this issue for a few days and still can't fix it. Basically what I'm trying to do is really simple. I'm trying to build **a discord bot** that **gets the Date at which something started and the Date at which that event has ended.** Specifically when the user types "start" I should register when it was written and after that register the time of "end" command.

Here is the code for **start**.

```
if (args == 'start') {

            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send(`<@${message.member.id}> you have to join a **voice channel** so we can catch your suspicious attempts lol`);

            if (user.studystarted) return message.channel.send(`<@${message.member.id}> Your study has started! whisper: *stop procrastinating*`);

            await profileModel.updateOne({
                userID: message.author.id,
            }, {
                $set: {
                    studystarted: true,

                },
                $currentDate: {
                    studystart: true,
                }


            }, {
                upsert: true,
            });
```

Here is the code for **end**;

```
    if (args == 'end') {

            if (!user.studystarted) return message.channel.send(`<@${message.member.id}> how are you going to end it if you haven't started?`);

            await profileModel.updateOne({
                userID: message.author.id,
            }, {

                $currentDate: {
                    studyend: true,
                }
            }, { upsert: true });


            let starttime = user.studystart;
            let endtime = user.studyend;

            console.log("start time: " + starttime);
            console.log("end time: " + endtime);

            let diffTime = (endtime.getTime() - starttime.getTime()) / 1000;

            await profileModel.updateOne({
                userID: message.author.id,
            }, {
                $inc: {
                    studytotal: diffTime,
                    weeklytime: diffTime
                },
                $set: {
                    studystarted: false,
                }
            });
```

I've tried many ways to set the date but I don't see any of it working. It almost always ends up end time being written before and start time written later which shouldn't be how it works.

Any suggestion is appreciated. *I'm a beginner*